# working with jar and so files in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, jar, xamarin.android

I'm working with Brother Label Printer "QL-710W" for printing purpose. I'm using Xamarin forms targeting Android for printing a web view content.

I'm facing problem in communicating with the printer. They have provided android demo application with code which is working fine for me in Android studio.

I'm trying to use provided .jar files and .so files in Xamarin Android. I'm stuck in adding and consuming .jar and dependent .so files.

Can any one suggest, How to add .jar files and .so files in binding project.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load createdata from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/PrintPOC.PrintPOC-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/PrintPOC.PrintPOC-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jason, I have gone through the post earlier, My issue is .Jar files are depend on .so files. Here I don't need to consume it. I just want to place .so files so that .jar files can refer .so files as normal.